# Using Feature Hashing with numpy array

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, scikit-learn

I have my dataset in a numpy array of dimension 10k X 30k. I was looking to do feature hashing but it seems we can only dataset in the form of a dictionary or string.

My numpy array format has 30,000 columns. Is there any way I can change this such that feature hasher accepts ?

Comment: Yes, make a dict out of it. But why hashing if the data are in a NumPy array already? The `sklearn.random_projection` module does pretty much the same thing, only faster.

Comment: Does it? Is there any proof about this?

Comment: No proof, just intuition based on the similarity between hash functions and PRNGs. Why do you want feature hashing for such an array? I'm asking because I co-implemented the hashing in scikit-learn, my own use case being symbolic feature spaces that dwarf yours.

Comment: I have a giant matrix on which I did do random projections, I wanted to compare it to feature hashing and see, results for space consumed and matrix approximation errors.

Comment: Is this question still unresolved? If not, please post your solution.